# Firebase startAt accept index

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I understand that startAt is designed to accept the value that the query is ordered by. For example, cities are ordered by their respective name, so I startAt a certain name and search onwards.

```
const q1 = query(collection(db, "cities"),
   orderBy("name"),
   startAt("Springfield")
```

Is it possible to instead start at a specific index, for example:

```
const q1 = query(collection(db, "cities"),
   orderBy("name"),
   startAt(5)
```

Is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to instead start at a specific index?

No, that's not possible. You cannot perform a query that only returns elements starting from a specific index. For example, let's assume you have a query that returns 7 documents. You cannot say, hey Firestore, ignore the first 5 documents, and return me only the last 2. That's not how it works. The only alternative that you have is to use `startAt()` function, as you already did in your first example.